# linq to DB search with contains

Tags: c#, linq, search

C# linq to DB search

```
query = query.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(text));
query = query.Where(x => x.Lastname.Contains(text));
query = query.Where(x => x.Number.Contains(text));
query = query.Where(x => x.Address.Contains(text));
query = query.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(text));
query = query.Skip(page * limit).Take(limit);
```

how to write this in one line? I always get 0 rows event if in DB i have 5 of them.

Comment: Do you want to combine them with `AND` or `OR`. above code is for `AND`.

Comment: Then you have your answers below.

Comment: But picked the wrong one :) You said they should be combined by `OR`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all constraints must be `and` together :

```
query = query
    .Where(x => x.Name.Contains(text) &&
        x.Lastname.Contains(text) &&
        x.Number.Contains(text) &&
        x.Address.Contains(text) &&
        x.Name.Contains(text))
    .Skip(page * limit)
    .Take(limit);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Basic LINQ Query Operations`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397927.aspx) in your task.

```
query.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(text) ||
    x.Lastname.Contains(text) ||
    x.Number.Contains(text) ||
    x.Number.Contains(text) ||
    x.Address.Contains(text)).Skip(page * limit).Take(limit).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write:

```
query = query.Where(x => x.Lastname.Contains(text) || x.Number.Contains(text) || 
    x.Address.Contains(text) || x.Name.Contains(text))
    .Skip(page * limit).Take(limit);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at a nuget package I have created

### http://www.nuget.org/packages/NinjaNye.SearchExtensions

This will enable you to do the following (and much more)

#### Performing an `OR` search (text exists in **any** of the properties)

```
var query = query.Search(text, x => x.Name, 
                               x => x.LastName,
                               x => x.Address,
                               x => x.Number)
                 .Skip(page * limit)
                 .Take(limit);
```

#### Performing an `AND` search (text exists in **all** of the properties)

```
var query = query.Search(text, x => x.Name)
                 .Search(text, x => x.LastName)
                 .Search(text, x => x.Address)
                 .Search(text, x => x.Number)
                 .Skip(page * limit)
                 .Take(limit);
```

For more information take a look at the **[projects GitHub page](https://github.com/ninjanye/SearchExtensions)** or my **[blog posts](http://jnye.co/posts/tagged/search-extensions)**

**UPDATE:** NinjaNye.SearchExtensions has now been updated to have a new [fluent api](http://jnye.co/fluent) meaning you can write the following:

```
var query = query.Search(x => x.Name, 
                         x => x.LastName,
                         x => x.Address,
                         x => x.Number)
                 .Containing(text)
                 .Skip(page * limit)
                 .Take(limit);
```

This will return records that have `text` contained in **any** of the defined properties